# WPF simple databinding

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

i want to bind textbox But it isn't display the string. Second thing is i want to update Name string periodically. Any solution?

here is my c# code:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
  public String Name = "text";
}
```

xaml code:

```
<Grid Name="myGrid" Height="300">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            NotifyCahnge("Name");

        }

    }

    private void NotifyChange(string prop)
    { 
        if(PropertyChanged!=null)
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 2):

You need to delcare Properties not field, what you have delcared here is a field.

```
public String Name {get; set;}
```

Plus it should not be in the Control file (UI file). Move it to separate class and set it as a DataContext.

PLus as Vlad pointed you need to Notify to UI that things changes, simple proprties doesn't have that.

Nice article on [dataBinding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26210/Moving-Toward-WPF-Data-Binding-One-Step-at-a-Time) :

Comment: This won't work, the OP needs to change the variable and have these changes reflected in the UI.

Comment: Of course. But he has a long way to go, I suggest reading some basics about dataBinding

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your `Name` as a `DependencyProperty`:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
    set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(Window1));
```

(Note that Visual Studio defines a handy snippet `propdp` for this, try typing `propdp` + <kbd>TAB</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>.)

Then, you need to bind correctly. Something like that:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

Comment: He needs to start by changing it from being a field , WPF doesn't bind to field properties.

Comment: @MBen: the OP needs to pick the changes, so he needs either DependencyProperty or INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @Vlad: In this situation the OP should use `INotifyPropertyChanged` and not a dependency property.

Comment: @Meleak: any backing of your claim?

Comment: @Meleak Both are fine, and Actually DependencyProperties are faster than using INotifyPropertyChanged http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx

Comment: In ViewModels, `INotifyPropertyChanged` is used since you usually don't bind these properties, change notification is enough. A dependency property is needed when you need to bind the property (`UserControls`, Custom controls etc) but in this scenario I don't see any reason for the OP to bind Name.

Comment: @MBen: Sure, both will work but you usually don't use Dependency Properties this way. I've almost never seen a reason to have a Dependency Property in a ViewModel.

Comment: @Meleak: first of all, there is no ViewModel, as the OP clearly doesn't use MVVM. Next, still "INotifyPropertyChanged may be used instead" isn't backing "INotifyPropertyChanged must be used".

Comment: I can see that the OP isn't using MVVM, that's not the point. My point is that the OP doesn't need to bind Name, he only needs change notification. But sure, both will work.

Comment: @Meleak: personally I prefer DPs, in order to spare thinking if I need animation/styling/back binding/whatever, when it's a property of the View class. (Even not considering performance, which is favourable to DPs.) IF the feature is available at low cost, why not use it? Window is already a DependencyObject. For VMs I'm usually more picky, they need a kind of design.

Answer (score 1):

WPF bindings work with **properties**, not fields. You need to define `Name` as a property, and also set the Window's data context:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
  public String Name { get; set; }

  public Window1()
  {
      Name = "text";
      DataContext = this;

      InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

You can also define it as a Dependency Property if you want to support change notification and other DP-related features or use `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I suggest you read more about WPF data binding [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx).